# Ошибка при работе с Tomcat:Connection refused: localhost:8080

Tags: java, java-ee, tomcat

Только начинаю разбираться. Скачал Tomcat, запустил его. Когда ввожу в адресную строку http://localhost:8080
в браузере выдает:

```
Connection refused: localhost:8080
```

При этом иконка самого томкэта сверху на вкладке имеется.

Log:

17-Mar-2017 14:57:57.073 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.12
17-Mar-2017 14:57:57.076 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Mar 8 2017 17:41:47 UTC
17-Mar-2017 14:57:57.077 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.12.0
17-Mar-2017 14:57:57.077 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 7
17-Mar-2017 14:57:57.077 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            6.1
17-Mar-2017 14:57:57.077 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          x86
17-Mar-2017 14:57:57.078 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre
17-Mar-2017 14:57:57.078 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.7.0_79-b15
17-Mar-2017 14:57:57.080 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
17-Mar-2017 14:57:57.080 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\new\apache-tomcat-8.5.12
17-Mar-2017 14:57:57.080 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\new\apache-tomcat-8.5.12
17-Mar-2017 14:57:57.081 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\new\apache-tomcat-8.5.12\conf\logging.properties
17-Mar-2017 14:57:57.081 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
17-Mar-2017 14:57:57.082 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
17-Mar-2017 14:57:57.082 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
17-Mar-2017 14:57:57.083 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\new\apache-tomcat-8.5.12
17-Mar-2017 14:57:57.084 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\new\apache-tomcat-8.5.12
17-Mar-2017 14:57:57.084 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\new\apache-tomcat-8.5.12\temp
17-Mar-2017 14:57:57.085 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\new\MVN\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;.
17-Mar-2017 14:57:57.220 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
17-Mar-2017 14:57:57.254 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
17-Mar-2017 14:57:57.259 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
17-Mar-2017 14:57:57.261 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
17-Mar-2017 14:57:57.262 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 599 ms
17-Mar-2017 14:57:57.294 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
17-Mar-2017 14:57:57.295 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.12
17-Mar-2017 14:57:57.335 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive C:\new\apache-tomcat-8.5.12\webapps\MyFirstWebProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
17-Mar-2017 14:57:58.079 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
17-Mar-2017 14:57:58.215 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [103] milliseconds.
17-Mar-2017 14:57:58.238 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive C:\new\apache-tomcat-8.5.12\webapps\MyFirstWebProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war has finished in 904 ms
17-Mar-2017 14:57:58.240 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive C:\new\apache-tomcat-8.5.12\webapps\Test-1.war
17-Mar-2017 14:57:58.628 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
17-Mar-2017 14:57:58.635 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive C:\new\apache-tomcat-8.5.12\webapps\Test-1.war has finished in 395 ms
17-Mar-2017 14:57:58.636 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\new\apache-tomcat-8.5.12\webapps\docs
17-Mar-2017 14:57:58.673 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\new\apache-tomcat-8.5.12\webapps\docs has finished in 37 ms
17-Mar-2017 14:57:58.674 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\new\apache-tomcat-8.5.12\webapps\examples
17-Mar-2017 14:57:59.315 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\new\apache-tomcat-8.5.12\webapps\examples has finished in 641 ms
17-Mar-2017 14:57:59.315 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\new\apache-tomcat-8.5.12\webapps\host-manager
17-Mar-2017 14:57:59.366 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\new\apache-tomcat-8.5.12\webapps\host-manager has finished in 50 ms
17-Mar-2017 14:57:59.366 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\new\apache-tomcat-8.5.12\webapps\manager
17-Mar-2017 14:57:59.413 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\new\apache-tomcat-8.5.12\webapps\manager has finished in 47 ms
17-Mar-2017 14:57:59.414 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\new\apache-tomcat-8.5.12\webapps\ROOT
17-Mar-2017 14:57:59.753 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
17-Mar-2017 14:57:59.759 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\new\apache-tomcat-8.5.12\webapps\ROOT has finished in 344 ms
17-Mar-2017 14:57:59.764 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8080]
17-Mar-2017 14:57:59.778 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
17-Mar-2017 14:57:59.783 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 2520 ms

Comment: Дабавте плиз лог при старте Tomcat

Comment: лог добавил. Только не знаю надо ли и как его форматировать, чтобы это было читабельно

Comment: на основании логов можно сказат томкат стартнулся нормально. Нужно уточнит .. может быть firewall блокирует порт. Попробуйте изменит порт в server.xml. Подробнее [здес](https://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-change-tomcat-default-port/). Если не поможет попробуйте 127.0.0.1 вместе localhost. Если и это не поможет попробуйте заного скачать  Tomcat c сайта может с Tomcat - ом что то не так

Comment: да в том то и дело, что это все проделывал. А вот 127.0.0.1 работает, но localhost - нет

Comment: Если 127.0.0.1 работает тогда можна дабавит локал днс. В папке **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc** в файл **hosts** довавит следюший запис **127.0.0.1       localhost**